# How to search for a string in a pdf document

Tags: java, file, java-8, java-stream, filereader

I have a pdf document which contains images, hyperlinks , words and many other things.

I want to search for a sting in all the words, i.e images and hyperlinks are excluded.
How to write a java code with that. Could someone help here.

Comment: Use `iText` java library

Comment: Can you please give some sample code where I can search a string using iText library

Comment: https://vkuzel.com/finding-a-text-in-a-pdf-file-with-itext  Google it, it's a famous library, you will find 100's of tutorial

Comment: try using pdfgrep. - sudo apt-get install pdfgrep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the PDFbox library of Apache (https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi).
Here is an example of code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type the directory of the PDF File : ");
        String PDFdir = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Input the phrase to find");
        String phrase = scan.nextLine();
        File file = new File(PDFdir);
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);
        PDFTextStripper findPhrase = new PDFTextStripper();
        String text = findPhrase.getText(doc);
        String PDF_content = text;
        String result = PDF_content.contains(phrase) ? "Yes" : "No"
        System.out.println(result);
        doc.close();
    }
}
```

**Remember you will have to download PDFbox jar file and import it into your project.**

Output/Result :

[image]

Edit:

You can also find the number of phrases in the PDF :

```
if (result.equals("Yes")) {
    int counter = 0;
        while(PDF_content.contains(phrase)) {
            counter++;
            PDF_content = PDF_content.replaceFirst(phrase, "");
        }
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

Output/Result :
[image]